# copy a cell containing single qoute

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell which contains the value `'13` (in cell) and showing `''13`(in fomula bar), when I copying the cell content to a variable it is returning as `'13`

```
variable1 = Range("A1").value
```

when I copying the variable1 to another excel sheet it showing as `13` in the cell and `'13` in the formula bar.

```
Range("B3").value = variable1
```

I know that `'` is used to convert the cell to text format

Could anyone helps me how to avoid this and get the value as `'13` in the cell (B3)

Comment: what do you want exactly? could you give a clearer example, or maybe some code of what you've tried

Comment: Try using `Range("A1").FormulaR1C1` instead of the `.Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution instead of copying it into a variable if use the following one

```
Range("A1").Copy Destination:=Range("B3")
```

it will copies the exact content to the other cell.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special property "PrefixCharacter" of Range object, which returns prefix of the cell value.
So your code may look like following:

```
variable1 = Range("A1").PrefixCharacter & Range("A1").value
Range("B3").value = variable1
```